# Is a constructor a move constructor if the parameter is not an object of the class?

Tags: c++, constructor, move, move-constructor

Does the && and in the parameters mean that this is a move constructor?

```
Vertex(int&& val, float&& dis)
            : value_(std::move(val)), distance_(std::move(dis)),
            known_(false), previous_in_path_(nullptr)
{}
```

Do all move constructors have to have a parameter that is an object of the same class as the constructor is in? Like this?

```
Vertex(Vertex&& rhs)
            : value_(std::move(rhs.value_)), distance_(std::move(rhs.distance_)),
            known_(false), previous_in_path_(nullptr)
{}
```

I just need clarification as to what is and what isn't a move constructor.

Comment: A move constructor has the form `class_name(class_name&&)`

Comment: The answer to the headline is 'No.' That first constructor is garbage. So is the second one.

Comment: The parameter `Blah&& blah` means that the `blah` object is *capable* & *allowed* to be moved.  The argument passed to the parameter has **not** been moved yet.  That occurs with a move-constructor or move-assignment — which is not required to happen, which in that case will leave the caller's argument not-moved.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Move constructors documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> A move constructor of class **T** is a non-template constructor whose
> **first parameter** is **T&&**, const **T&&**, volatile **T&&**, or const volatile
> **T&&**, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the
> parameters all have default values.

(*emphasis is mine*)

This means that in order to be a move constructor, the first parameter must be a rvalue reference (potentially const/volatile) to the **same type**.
You can add additional parameters, but they must have default values.

Therefore your 1st constructor is **not** a move constructor, but the 2nd one is.